# Как изменить размер массива обрезав ненужные данные?

Tags: python, numpy

Есть массив:

```py
arr = [[0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 3,5, 6, 7,0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1,1, 1, 1,7, 0, 0],
       [0, 7, 1,1, 1, 1,1, 7, 0],
       [0, 7, 1,1, 1, 1,1, 7, 0],
       [0, 7, 1,1, 1, 1,7, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 7,7, 7, 7,0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0]]
```

Надо получить что-то на подобие вот этого:

```py
result_array = [[ 0, 3,5, 6, 7,0, 0, ],
                [ 1, 1,1, 1, 1,7, 0, ],
                [ 7, 1,1, 1, 1,1, 7, ],
                [ 7, 1,1, 1, 1,1, 7, ],
                [ 7, 1,1, 1, 1,7, 0, ],
                [ 0, 7,7, 7, 7,0, 0, ]]
```

Задаю маску для поиска отсутствующих данных:

```py
mask = arr==0
```

Как получить обрезанный массив без отсутствующих данных (=0)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь функционалом `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 3,5, 6, 7,0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1,1, 1, 1,7, 0, 0],
       [0, 7, 1,1, 1, 1,1, 7, 0],
       [0, 7, 1,1, 1, 1,1, 7, 0],
       [0, 7, 1,1, 1, 1,7, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 7,7, 7, 7,0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0]])
```

Сам код:

```
res = arr[~np.all(arr == 0, axis=1)]
res = res[:, ~np.all(res == 0, axis=0)]
print(res)
```

Результат:

```
[[0 3 5 6 7 0 0]
 [1 1 1 1 1 7 0]
 [7 1 1 1 1 1 7]
 [7 1 1 1 1 1 7]
 [7 1 1 1 1 7 0]
 [0 7 7 7 7 0 0]]
```

Comment: `~np.all(arr == 0, axis=1)` можно заменить на метод `any` -> `arr.any(axis=1)`

Comment: @strawdog ответ хороший, потому что можно ввести любое значение non data

Answer (score 3):

Конечно же можно использовать транспонирование через `zip`:

```
from pprint import pprint

arr = [[0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 3,5, 6, 7,0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1,1, 1, 1,7, 0, 0],
       [0, 7, 1,1, 1, 1,1, 7, 0],
       [0, 7, 1,1, 1, 1,1, 7, 0],
       [0, 7, 1,1, 1, 1,7, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 7,7, 7, 7,0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0]]

pprint(list(zip(*filter(any, zip(*filter(any, arr))))))

# [(0, 3, 5, 6, 7, 0, 0),
#  (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 7, 0),
#  (7, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 7),
#  (7, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 7),
#  (7, 1, 1, 1, 1, 7, 0),
#  (0, 7, 7, 7, 7, 0, 0)]
```

Немного поясненений:

1. `filter(any, arr)` - отсеиваем строки, состоящие из нулей
2. `zip(*filter(any, arr))` - транспонируем матрицу из оставшихся строк
3. `filter(any, zip(*filter(any, arr)))` - аналогично первому пункту, но уже на транспонированной матрице (отсеиваем строки, которые раньше были столбцами)
4. `zip(*filter(any, zip(*filter(any, arr))))` - транспонируем обратно

Answer (score 3):

Можно воспользоваться методом [numpy.nonzero()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html), возвращающим индексы ненулевых элементов по каждой размерности / оси:

```
nz = np.nonzero(arr)
res = arr[nz[0].min():nz[0].max()+1, nz[1].min():nz[1].max()+1]
```

---

результат:

```
In [19]: res
Out[19]:
array([[0, 3, 5, 6, 7, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 7, 0],
       [7, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 7],
       [7, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 7],
       [7, 1, 1, 1, 1, 7, 0],
       [0, 7, 7, 7, 7, 0, 0]])
```

Comment: Только к верней границе +1, она же исключающая! `nz[0].max() + 1` и `nz[1].max() + 1`.

Comment: @mkkik, да совсем вылетело из головы, спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

```
def v_trim_array(multi_array):
    zero_index = None

    for index in range(len(multi_array[0])):
        flag = False
        for array in multi_array:
            if array[index]:
                flag = True
            if zero_index is not None:
                array[zero_index] = array[index]
        if flag:
            zero_index += 1
        else:
            if zero_index is None:
                zero_index = index

    for array in reversed(multi_array):
        del array[zero_index:]


def h_trim_array(multi_array):
    zero_index = None

    for index, array in enumerate(multi_array):
        if any(array):
            if zero_index is not None:
                multi_array[zero_index] = array
                zero_index += 1
        else:
            if zero_index is None:
                zero_index = index

    del multi_array[zero_index:]


multi_array = [
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 3, 5, 6, 7, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 7, 0, 0],
    [0, 7, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 7, 0],
    [0, 7, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 7, 0],
    [0, 7, 1, 1, 1, 1, 7, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 7, 7, 7, 7, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
]

# сначала убираем нулевые строки (по горизонтали)
h_trim_array(multi_array)
# затем убираем нулевые столбцы (по вертикали)
v_trim_array(multi_array)

for array in multi_array:
    print(' '.join(map(str, array)))

# 0 3 5 6 7 0 0
# 1 1 1 1 1 7 0
# 7 1 1 1 1 1 7
# 7 1 1 1 1 1 7
# 7 1 1 1 1 7 0
# 0 7 7 7 7 0 0
```